# How to select a downloaded image based on screen density?

Tags: android, image, download

I know how to get the screen density, and I know how to make images and put them in drawable-ldpi, mdpi, hdpi so that the correct one is automatically used for the device.  What I want to know is if there is a way to download images that will be selected in a similarly automatic fashion based on screen density?  In other words, can I download three versions of an image and tell my app to automatically select the version that is appropriate to screen density?  Or would I have to code this myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to send this hdpi/mdpi value to server and there have appropriate logic to determine and send the correct screen type. Note that with latest version of Android they have added additional parameters so take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) for that.

Comment: That may be the only way to do it, but that's not quite what I was hoping for.  The question being -- is there a built in Android support to do this.  I get from your reply that the answer is no?

Comment: The way android would be able to do this is if you were able to download to the appropriate res folder. The problem is you cant download to res folder. Another approach may be to make another apk, and have your main app apk download this apk. I havent tried this but this approach should work.

Comment: That would be an interesting approach, but not for what I'm wanting to do.   Well, looks like you have the best answer so I'll give it to you.  Thanks for the suggestions!